# Opening the terminal in R

Tags: r

According to most articles on R the terminal simply shows up as a tab next to console in R or can be opened with shift+alt+R, however i still do not get anything

[a picture of the workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWsKF.png)l do not get the terminal.

Comment: "According to most articles" - please share the link. Or did you mean to use RStudio terminal? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010737148-Using-the-RStudio-Terminal

Answer (score 3):

The "terminal"-tab next to "console" is for RStudio and you are not using RStudio. Thats why you cant use the Shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! it seems like a flaw in the google data analytics course as they talk about opening the terminal before describing r studio which comes later in the course